# onActivityResult always get Activity.RESULT_CANCELED when take picture in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, camera, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have this situation: two Fragments inside a FragmentActivity. I have a method to take pictures and I would like to get the results from `onActivityResult`. The problem is the method `onActivityResult` always have `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`. I was using the same methods in an Activity before and they were working well. Code is below (comments are in Portuguese but I think that can't be a problem because code here is quite simple).
I have seen similar question but no one could help me.

```
public class CameraActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
{
        private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
        Fragment fragmentToqueParaTirarFoto;
        Fragment fragmentFotoCarregada;

        // Constantes para abrir activity de tirar foto e escolher foto do álbum
        private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

        String caminhoDaPastaDeFotos = "";
        String arquivoFullPath = "";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera, menu);
            return true;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult( requestCode,  resultCode,  data);
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE)
            {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                             /***********************************
                                   CODE NEVER REACHED THIS POINT.
                             ***********************************/

                    Log.d(TAG, "Result OK");
                }

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result Cancel");
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Função que abre intent para tirar foto. É adicionado parâmetro extra
         */
        public void takePicture()
        {
            // Intent que abre camera.
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

            // Novo nome do arquivo
            arquivoFullPath = newFileName();

            String identificadorDeArquivo = "file://";

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.parse(identificadorDeArquivo + arquivoFullPath);

            // Adiciona nome absoluto do arquivo da foto tirada
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        // Inicia intent com camera.
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    /**
     * Gera nome do arquivo com o mesmo formato de nome gerado pelo Android. O
     * formato do nome é IMG_ + yyyyMMdd_HHmmss + .jpg onde yyyyMMdd_HHmmss é a
     * hora local.
     * 
     * @return Retorna nome absoluto para imagem usando formato: IMG_ +
     *         yyyyMMdd_HHmmss + .jpg
     */
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private String newFileName()
    {

        // Formato de data
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(getResources().getString(
                R.string.string_formato_de_data_para_nome_do_arquivo));

        // Data atual
        Date date = new Date();

        // Nome do arquivo
        String newFileName = "IMG_" + dateFormat.format(date).toString()
                + ".jpg";

        // Nome absoluto para a nova imagem gerada.
        arquivoFullPath = caminhoDaPastaDeFotos + newFileName;

        return arquivoFullPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it already. My problem was path. I was using string with path+filename+extension and the path was empty(""). Now I put path for a folder in SD card and this problem now is solved. Sorry for disturb. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can answer your own question.